# Parsing a Stock API that contain dates as keys using the Codable protocol

Tags: json, swift, parsing, codable

I am trying to parse a stock api from `Alpha Vantage`. 
This is what a response looks like:  [API Response Demo](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&apikey=demo)

I set up Four classes to use for decoding and encoding:

1. Stocks
2. Meta Data
3. Time Series
4. Open High Low Close

I think the problem lies in the Time Series Classes since i am suppose to be getting an array dates as a Key, which each contain Open, Close, High, Low values. All three classes conform to the `Codable` protocol.I changed the value of the keys in the enum so that it could match the correct `JSON Response`.

```
    var stocks = [Stocks]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    loadURL()
}


func loadURL(){
    let stocksURL = URL(string: "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&apikey=demo")
    print("Inside loadURL")
    guard let url = stocksURL else { return }
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url){
        print("Inside data")
        parse(json: data)
    }
}

func parse(json: Data){
    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    print("before Decoding")
    if let json = try? jsonDecoder.decode([Stocks].self, from: json){
        print("Inside parsing")
        stocks = json
        print(stocks[0].meta_data.symbol)
        print(stocks[0].time_series.OHLC[0].open)
    }
}
}

class Stocks: Codable {
var meta_data: MetaData
var time_series: TimeSeries

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case meta_data   = "Meta Data"
    case time_series = "Time Series (5min)"
}
}

class MetaData: Codable {
var information: String
var symbol: String
var lastRefreshed: String
var outputSize: String
var timeZone: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case information   = "1. Information"
    case symbol        = "2. Symbol"
    case lastRefreshed = "3. Last Refreshed"
    case outputSize    = "4. Output Size"
    case timeZone      = "5. Time Zone"
}
}

class TimeSeries: Codable {
var OHLC: [OpenHighLowClose]
}

class OpenHighLowClose: Codable {
var open: Double
var high: Double
var low: Double
var close: Double
var volume: Double

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case open   = "1. open"
    case high   = "2. high"
    case low    = "3. low"
    case close  = "4. close"
    case volume = "5. volume"
}
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question but never use `Data(contentsOf:)` to load remote data on the main queue. Very bad. Use `URLSession` to get the data. Properly embrace the async nature of loading remote data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the proper data types w.r.t your response

```
// MARK: - Response
struct Response: Codable {
    let metaData: MetaData
    let timeSeries5Min: [String: TimeSeries5Min]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case metaData = "Meta Data"
        case timeSeries5Min = "Time Series (5min)"
    }
}

// MARK: - MetaData
struct MetaData: Codable {
    let the1Information, the2Symbol, the3LastRefreshed, the4Interval: String
    let the5OutputSize, the6TimeZone: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case the1Information = "1. Information"
        case the2Symbol = "2. Symbol"
        case the3LastRefreshed = "3. Last Refreshed"
        case the4Interval = "4. Interval"
        case the5OutputSize = "5. Output Size"
        case the6TimeZone = "6. Time Zone"
    }
}

// MARK: - TimeSeries5Min
struct TimeSeries5Min: Codable {
    let the1Open, the2High, the3Low, the4Close: String
    let the5Volume: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case the1Open = "1. open"
        case the2High = "2. high"
        case the3Low = "3. low"
        case the4Close = "4. close"
        case the5Volume = "5. volume"
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
  func loadURL() {
    let stocksURL = URL(string: "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&apikey=demo")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: stocksURL!) { (data, response, error) in
      if let error = error {
        print(error)
        return
      }
      do {
        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data!)
        response.timeSeries5Min.forEach({ (keyValue) in
          print(keyValue)
        })
      } catch {
        print(error)
      }
    }.resume()
  }
```

Comment: So it is there a reason why it would be better to do a URLSession over  Data(contentsOf: url) . It seemed like doing Data(contentsOf) would be more readable. I am still new to this so just wondering.

Comment: You should load data asynchronously so that your App does not look stuck during the loading. You should notice that when you are loading data using  `if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {`, your app gets stuck for the time response is not received which is bad for user experience.

Comment: You can show an activity indicator/spinner while fetching data asynchronously as above.