# Json Parsing Swift using an Api (alpha vantage)

Tags: arrays, json, swift, api, parsing

### Swift Json Parse

I am trying to parse the json to assign the values. I am new to swift and cannot find the solution on YouTube or the web. I am not sure if I have to have the construct identical to what is inside the "" for the json but there is a space. Additionally I am not sure if the date is used to call the Information for the day.

```
struct Stock: Decodable {
let symbol: String
let open: Double
let high: Double
let low: Double
let close: Double
let volume: Int
}
    
var tag : String = "TSLA"

    let url =  URL(string: "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=TSLA&apikey=/(key)")

    let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            
        // pull what is coming from the interent
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }
        
        // print the data but it wont be unpacked
        if let data = data {
            print(data)
        }
            
        // json serialization
            
        do{
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
            print(json)
            
            let stock = try
            JSONDecoder().decode(Stock.self, from: data!)
            print(Stock.init(symbol: String, open: Double, high: Double, low: Double, close: Double, volume: Int))
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
            }
            
}.resume()
```

example of the print json:

```
"Meta Data" =     {
        "1. Information" = "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes";
        "2. Symbol" = TSLA;
        "3. Last Refreshed" = "2020-06-01";
        "4. Output Size" = Compact;
        "5. Time Zone" = "US/Eastern";
    };
    "Time Series (Daily)" =     {
        "2020-01-08" =         {
            "1. open" = "473.7000";
            "2. high" = "498.4900";
            "3. low" = "468.2300";
            "4. close" = "492.1400";
            "5. volume" = 31199393;
        };
        "2020-01-09" =         {
            "1. open" = "497.1000";
            "2. high" = "498.8000";
            "3. low" = "472.8700";
            "4. close" = "481.3400";
            "5. volume" = 28463186;
        };
        "2020-01-10" =         {
            "1. open" = "481.7900";
            "2. high" = "484.9400";
            "3. low" = "473.7000";
            "4. close" = "478.1500";
            "5. volume" = 12976832;
```

Comment: Two fatal mistakes: 1) You have to decode from the top (the dictionary with keys `Meta Data` and `Time Series (Daily)`) 2) You have to add CodingKeys to map the keys containing spaces and starting with a digit to valid struct member names. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56485249/parsing-a-stock-api-that-contain-dates-as-keys-using-the-codable-protocol

Comment: Mistake #3: Be aware that according to the JSON specification **everything** in double quotes is `String`, even `"481.3400"` and `"false"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your struct like this and decode as follows:-

Struct:

```swift
struct Stock: Codable {
    let metaData: MetaData
    let timeSeriesDaily: [String: TimeSeriesDaily]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case metaData = "Meta Data"
        case timeSeriesDaily = "Time Series (Daily)"
    }
}

struct MetaData: Codable {
    let the1Information, the2Symbol, the3LastRefreshed, the4OutputSize: String
    let the5TimeZone: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case the1Information = "1. Information"
        case the2Symbol = "2. Symbol"
        case the3LastRefreshed = "3. Last Refreshed"
        case the4OutputSize = "4. Output Size"
        case the5TimeZone = "5. Time Zone"
    }
}

struct TimeSeriesDaily: Codable {
    let the1Open, the2High, the3Low, the4Close: String
    let the5Volume: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case the1Open = "1. open"
        case the2High = "2. high"
        case the3Low = "3. low"
        case the4Close = "4. close"
        case the5Volume = "5. volume"
    }
}
```

URLSession:

```swift
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=TSLA&apikey=TSLA")!) { (data, _, _) in
    let stock = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Stock.self, from: data!)
    print(stock)
}.resume()
```

Note: This is just an example, you're supposed to handle the errors by your self.